# ICommunicationObject.State is not updated

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I'm using ICommunicationObject.State in order to check the channel state.
The problem is that once it changed to opened state it doesn't changed again when it is faulted.

I added a sample of my code
thanks

```
AnnouncementClient _client;

void func1()
{
        try
        {

            Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            if (_isDiscoveryProxyConnected)
            {
                if (_client.InnerChannel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    _isDiscoveryProxyConnected = false;
                }

            }

            else
            {
                _client = new AnnouncementClient(new AnnouncementEndpoint(binding, announcementEndPoint));
                foreach (var endpointDiscoveryMetadata in _endpoints)
                {
                    _client.AnnounceOnline(endpointDiscoveryMetadata);
                    _discoveryProxyMetadata = endpointDiscoveryMetadata;
                }


                _isDiscoveryProxyConnected = true;

           }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the state... 
I keep doing AnnouncementClient also after I recieveig connection...
I just change the timer so it will do AnnouncementClient in bigger intervals...
if it fails so I take down the intervals again...